# How to run Play Application on Apache 2 server?

Tags: apache, playframework

I'm completely new to this, so please forgive me.

What I have right now is a Play application that, when I run `play run` on my personal Mac the site launches on localhost:9000 and everything works fine.

I also have a server running CentOS that tells me to "add content to the directory `/var/www/html/`" when I navigate to it's IP, but I don't understand how I can do that with a Play application? It's not like I have a bunch of HTML files I can just put there?

So my question is, what steps do I need to take to make it so if I go to the IP of my server, it takes me to the website I made and that is currently stored on my Mac?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure Apache as a "proxy" to your Play application (that's why you won't need to put anything into `/var/www/html/`).

Your application code can be uploaded anywhere you want on the server. It will need to be started on the server (with `play start` for example) and Apache will "forward" requests to the running Play application.

You can look at the Play documentation in the "Deploy your application" section :

- "Deploying your application" (general recommandations) : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Production
- "Set-up a front-end HTTP server" (explain how to deploy Play behind Apache or Nginx) : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/HTTPServer